# Unable to send DAO in MyEtherWallet due to insufficient gas

Tags: the-dao, dao, myetherwallet

I was trying to send 1 DAO from Myetherwallet to another address and wanted to know if it worked. However, I was not able to send due to insufficient funds for gas * price + value. I had 150000 gas for the transaction fee. Screenshots attached. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you just try to increase the gas?

Comment: I just made a successful tx with 2 000 000 gas (randomly chosen big number).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your transaction failed is that you have insufficient funds in your account to pay for the gas to execute the transaction.

Looking at your account at [5C8a1cbEF21403B2D708796ea2F050F517393b91](https://live.ether.camp/account/5C8a1cbEF21403B2D708796ea2F050F517393b91), you have a balance of 0.000229089 ETH . This balance is also shown in your screen print above.

Looking at the cost of a transaction to The DAO that executed successfully ([0xf14cdcdc03903945abe514649eb9e55eb2d710d4be7c8c1696ebfe635f8f287c](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xf14cdcdc03903945abe514649eb9e55eb2d710d4be7c8c1696ebfe635f8f287c)), the transaction fee is 0.00095556 ethers, and this is more than is available in your account balance.

And here is another successfully executed transaction to The DAO ([0xf50a5d149d5b1fd896716cb273f4a789e9bf50226766424874ed3589ac5960e2](http://etherscan.io/tx/0xf50a5d149d5b1fd896716cb273f4a789e9bf50226766424874ed3589ac5960e2)) that has a transaction fee of 0.00065556 ethers.

**Q**: How to resolve this issue?

You will have to add a bit more ethers to your account before you can transfer the DAO from your account.

Comment: Noted Bokky. I initially thought that I could pay the gas price using my DAO tokens.  Also, could you help with my other question relating to the balance issue (http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/dao-balance-in-myetherwallet-differs-from-balance-in-etherscan)? I am still experimenting in the DAO environement.