# DAO balance in MyEtherWallet differs from balance in EtherScan.io

Tags: the-dao, dao, myetherwallet

I was experimenting with my DAO tokens and found out that the balance in Myetherwallet differs from the balance in [EtherScan.io - 0x5C8a1cbEF21403B2D708796ea2F050F517393b91](https://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO?a=0x5C8a1cbEF21403B2D708796ea2F050F517393b91).

Screenshot showing the balance in Myetherwallet attached.

Any idea to resolve this balance issue?[image]

Comment: I've checked you etherscan.io link and daohub.org and your token balance is 99.72 dao. I'll leave it to `@tayvano` (co-founder of MyEtherWallet) to work out why MEW is showing a zero balance.

Answer (score 2):

Few hours ago the DAO address was wrong (see at [Github](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/commit/4ef24b9db9c494e294dd200f1046adba0c921620)): it was 0xd838f9c9792bf8398e1f5fbfbd3b43c5a86445aa (author's test account, I suppose) instead of 0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413. It can happen when you work both on test and main net.

In any case, even if I'm sure the author is acting in good faith, there's no way for you to know what that page is really calling behind. This one of the many reasons I suggest to **NEVER** use third parties online services to act in your behalf when using distributed apps.

If you really don't want to use the official Mist client and you prefer to use applications like MyEtherWallet, download it and install it on your server. It will be interesting and you can learn a lot about Ethereum/DApp programming (and the same if you download the Mist source code of course).

Comment: 0xd838f9c9792bf8398e1f5fbfbd3b43c5a86445aa is a testdao on the mainnet that we were using to test before the creation period ended. This was removed before going live though.

Answer (score 1):

We are having sporadic and seemingly random issues with displaying the token balance correctly at times. This has been happening for a few days now and we have been trying different things to, seemingly, no avail.

On both our computers and all browsers, our balance works so it's super hard to figure out. However, it's **purely a front-end display / UI issue** and you will be able to sen DAO tokens without issue.

We have one fix in the works that we will push live tonight.

Please let me know your browser and OS and if you see any errors in the console (right click -> inspect element -> console). I will add your report to the list to see if we can detect a pattern.

Comment: Noted. I had a reason why I did not use the MIST client. The Mist client (version Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-7-4) is simply taking too long to sync. I've been waiting for a week to have it synced and it is still syncing. I'm still experimenting the ether's infrastructure. Such an experience is hard for a layperson to use it for transferring funds/assets on a daily basis. It should be built in a simple way just like a layperson finds information from the internet by typing the site address.   My browser is Google Chrome and OS is Windows 10. Console as in the ether client 'MIST'?